# A suspicious mark on turtle's nose

Tags: health, turtles

I just noticed a suspicious-looking mark on my turtle's nose today, and I’m not sure what the cause is. I tried wiping it off and nothing happened

Could someone let me know what it is and whether I should be concerned?

Comment: you need to give us more to go on,please provide more details.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Pets, could you please include a few photos of this mark in your question?

Comment: i vote to close this question for now until the OP add the information we need to answer it,we can allways open it later if/when the information is added.